# При нажатие на блок должен прилетать сверху список но он не появляется

Tags: javascript, html, css, всплывающее-окно

При нажатие на блок(drop__title) должен прилетать сверху список(drop__menu) но он не появляется, также у блока (drop__title) есть псевдо элемент (стрелочка), она должна переворачиваться на 180deg при прилете списка

```js
let dropBtn = document.querySelector('.drop__title');
let dropMenu = document.querySelector('.drop__menu');

dropBtn.addEventListener('click',function () {
    dropMenu.classList.toggle('.drop-active');
});
```

```css
.drop__title {
    display: block;
    max-width: 728px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    font-family: "Montserrat Regular", sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 160%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.drop__title::after {
    content: url(../image/drop-menu__arrow.svg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s 0s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s 0s;
}
.drop__menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s 0s;
    background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.9);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    z-index: 2;
}
.drop__menu.drop-active {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    .drop__menu.drop-active.drop__title::after {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    .services__list {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    max-width: 728px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #272727;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop__title">Товарные знаки</div>
                                <div class="drop__menu">
                                    <ul class="services__list">
                                        <li class="services__item">Все услуги</li>
                                        <li class="services__item services__item_active">Товарные знаки</li>
                                        <li class="services__item">Патенты</li>
                                        <li class="services__item">Дизайн</li>
                                        <li class="services__item">IT</li>
                                        <li class="services__item">Защита</li>
                                        <li class="services__item">Управление</li>
                                        <li class="services__item">Обучение</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ```dropMenu.classList.toggle('.drop-active'); ```--> ```dropMenu.classList.toggle('drop-active');```

Comment: soledar10, не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

```js
let dropBtn = document.querySelector('.drop__title');
let dropMenu = document.querySelector('.drop__menu');

dropBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('drop__title--active');
  dropMenu.classList.toggle('drop-active');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.drop__item {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 728px;
}

.drop__title {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  font-family: "Montserrat Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 160%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
}

.drop__title::after {
  content: '\25BA';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s 0s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s 0s;
}

.drop__menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s 0s;
  background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.9);
  transform: translateY(-300%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.drop__menu.drop-active {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.drop__title--active::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.services__list {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  max-width: 728px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #272727;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop__item">
  <div class="drop__title">Товарные знаки</div>
  <div class="drop__menu">
    <ul class="services__list">
      <li class="services__item">Все услуги</li>
      <li class="services__item services__item_active">Товарные знаки</li>
      <li class="services__item">Патенты</li>
      <li class="services__item">Дизайн</li>
      <li class="services__item">IT</li>
      <li class="services__item">Защита</li>
      <li class="services__item">Управление</li>
      <li class="services__item">Обучение</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста а почему мой код не работал, он вроде похож?

Comment: @Дима Ярощук - Ошибка 1 - ```dropMenu.classList.toggle('.drop-active');```  Ошибка 2 - ```.drop__menu.drop-active.drop__title::after {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }```